# How to setup log rotation in AEM web console?

Tags: log4j, aem

We need to setup log rotation based on file-sizes as well as time duration of log statements in AEM's web console. Therefore putting up this query to know what are the best practices / experience-based recommendations for going about the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way sling logging is setup you could either use scheduled rotation or size based rotation, both can not be used simultaneously in a single configuration.

There are more details around the loggers in sling documentation [here](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/development/logging.html#log-file-rotation)

One thing you could try, is to have two writer configuration for a same logger file (not sure if this works but console allows you to configure it), one with scheduled configuration (daily) and another with size configuration.

[image: Logger Writer Configuration]

[image: Scheduled rotation]

[image: Size based rotation]

The best practice per say,

- You need to have proper logging level set for the production instances so that the right amount of required logging happens, no noise is logged.
- In my personal experience, we have followed daily log rotations and average file size was not more than 10 MB
- For instances lower than production it makes more sense to have size based rotation as those logs are usually required for debug purposes so the amount of logging tends to increase if you use daily rotation. And it becomes difficult to process those huge files with normal text editors.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this Adobe AEM forum post:- http://help-forums.adobe.com/content/adobeforums/en/experience-manager-forum/adobe-experience-manager.topic.html/forum__1w7b-hi_i_have_implem.html

// this post talks about "Log rotation based on size"

```
You can rotate CRX log through configuration in /crx-quickstart/server/runtime/0/_crx/WEB-INF/log4j.xml by changing configuration of 

<appender name="error" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="crx-quickstart/logs/crx/error.log"/>
        <param name="maxFileSize" value="10MB"/>
        <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="20"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss} *%-5p* %c{1}: %m (%F, line %L)%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>
```

You can edit "maxFileSize" or "maxBackupIndex" as per you need.

I hope this would help You.

Thanks and Regards

Kautuk Sahni